# Squash unpushed commits automatically

Tags: git

I currently just use `rebase` for it, e.g.

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

this brings me my text editor and then I manually mark all the commits with `s` except the first commit.

Is it possible to do this automatically, without editing textual file?

Comment: I believe this would be the best way to do this, not a git expert though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on `master` (the local one), and that it is ahead of `origin/master` by some commits, you could just do this:

```
git checkout -b tempbranch origin/master
git merge --squash master
git checkout master
git reset --hard tempbranch
git branch -D tempbranch
```

Now your `master` branch has a single commit ahead of `origin/master` that is the result of squashing all your previous commits.

The process would be similar if you're on a side branch, except steps 2 and 3 above would reference that branch instead of `master`. The results might not be quite as expected, though, depending on where `git merge-base mybranch origin/master` is relative to `origin/master` (i.e. if `origin/master` has advanced since the side branch was created). We'd have to know more about your actual branch topology to give better advice in that case...

Comment: Copied and pasted this into console, hit enter a couple times, and lost several hours of work.

Comment: @GirkovArpa *never* execute commands copied from the internet without understanding what they do.  `git` is usually very good at preventing you from losing data, but `git reset --hard` is one of those commands that can discard changes.  `git` is a sharp knife; yield it carefully.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a new commit that shares the tree of HEAD, use git commit-tree.  That is, if your current history looks like:

```
A-B-C-D-E
```

And you want

```
 A-B-E'
```

Where E' and E have the same content (here, B would be origin/master), just do:

```
git reset $( git commit-tree $(git cat-file -p HEAD | 
    awk '/tree/{print $2}') -p origin/master -m 'Squash')
```

There's probably a better way to get the tree of HEAD that doesn't involve piping to awk, but this should work just fine.

-- EDIT --

Thanks to @Guildenstern, modern git allows you to do:

```
git reset $(git commit-tree HEAD^{tree} -p origin/master -m 'Squash')
```

Comment: `HEAD^{tree}` :)

Comment: @Guildenstern  Thanks!  I wonder if that notation was available back in 2014.  Will edit to include.

Comment: `Introduce notation "ref^{type}"` from commit 5385f52da80be0d01f dated Thu Oct 13 18:57:40 2005, so it was definitely available in 2014!